# Setting a predefined value in a play framework form

Tags: playframework, ebean

I am trying to make a form in play framework which has a email field already defined,for this i have set a value in session. 
I just want to set  attributes placeholder and value in my input email field through this session ,i am doing this

```
@(userForm: Form[models.User] )

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._


@main(Html("Create")) {


<fieldset>
    <legend>Add a new User</legend>

   @form(action = routes.ShopController.submit(), 'id -> "shopCreationForm", 'class -> "form-horizontal", 'role->"form") {

    <div class="form-group"><label>Name:</label><input type=text class="form-control" label="Shop Name"></div>

    <div class="form-group"><label>Email:</label><input type=text class="form-control" label="Email" placeholder=@session.get("email") value=@session.get("email") readonly></div>




 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create">
        <a href="@routes.ApplicationController.index" class="btn">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
        }
        }
```

but it doesnt showing the email of a person set in email session field value.
I tried to google it out but unable to get anything
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's about Java controllers and/or Ebean models, isn't it ? fix your tags pls.

Comment: oops my mistake,thanks biesior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a... new `User` object and set required values WITHOUT saving it to DB in the controller (*pseudo code!*):

```
User user = new User();
user.email = session("email");
Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class);
return ok(newUserView.render(userForm.fill(user));
```

Benefit: using this approach + several conditions in the view you can use single view for creating/editing users.